# Which Cisco access points (and what IOS versions) does the AIR-CT2504 wireless LAN controller support?

Tags: cisco, cisco-wireless, cisco-wlc

I have two Cisco 1140 access points and two Cisco 1252AG access points. Can I use the Cisco AIR-CT2504 WLC to manage all of them? What versions of the LWAPP Cisco IOS are required? I tried looking for a compatibility matrix, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Cisco release notes for the Cisco 2504 Wireless LAN Controller, the last software, that supported the Cisco 1140 Series AP and Cisco 1250 Series AP is Releases 8.0.150.0 (31-Aug-2017) and 8.0.152.0 (21-Oct-2017).

From Cisco documentation:

> **Supported Access Point Platforms**
>
> The following access point platforms are supported in this release:
>
> - Cisco Aironet 1040, 1130, 1140, 1240, 1250, 1260, 1600, 1700, 2600,    2700, 3500, 3600, 3700, Cisco 600 Series OfficeExtend, 700, AP801,
>     and AP802 Series indoor access points
> - Cisco Aironet 1520 (1522, 1524), 1530, 1550 (1552), 1570, and    Industrial Wireless 3700 Series outdoor and industrial wireless
>     access points

You can still download the 8.0.150.0 and 8.0.152.0 software from Cisco software center.

Source:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/release/notes/crn80mr5.html#pgfId-1142589

Cisco 2500 Series Wireless LAN controller complete release notes:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/wireless/2500-series-wireless-controllers/products-release-notes-list.html